# Reshape a 4D Matrix into a 3D Matrix in Python

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I am trying to reshape a 4D matrix of temperature data for one year (shape: [month, day, latitude, longitude]) into a 3D matrix (shape: [day, latitude, longitude]).

I thought I had figured out a way to do this (see the code below), but when I check if the number of occurrences of each data value is the same in both matrices, they are not. So apparently my method of approach failed.

Does anybody know some other efficient way (perhaps with a python function) to reshape a matrix of many dimensions into one with less?

P.S. I can live with the "-9999.0 values" that linger in the 3D matrix for months with days < 31, as I can always mask them later. My problem is that apparently I fail to reshape the 4D matrix into the 3D. D.S.

```
import numpy as np

# Create some fake data
TEMP = np.random.randint(10.0, size=(12,31,40,60))
TEMP_ReSh = np.full(([372,40,60]), -9999.0)
M31 = [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12]
M30 = [4, 6, 9, 11]
M28 = [2]
count = 0
for m in M31:
    print('Reshaping months with 31 days')
    for d in np.arange(31):
        TEMP_ReSh[count, :, :] = TEMP[m-1,d,:,:]
        count = count + 1
print('Done with months of 31 days')
for m in M30:
    print('Reshaping months with 30 days')
    for d in np.arange(30):
        TEMP_ReSh[count, :, :] = TEMP[m-1,d,:,:]
        count = count + 1
print('Done with months of 30 days')
for m in M28:
    print('Reshaping February')
    for d in np.arange(28):
        TEMP_ReSh[count, :, :] = TEMP[m-1,d,:,:]
        count = count + 1
print('Done with February')

# Check if the number of occurrences of each integer value are the same for the 4D and 3D matrices:
TEMP_check = np.zeros([10,1])
TEMP_ReSh_check = np.zeros([10,1])
for n in np.arange(10):
    TEMP_check[n] = np.count_nonzero(TEMP == n)
    TEMP_ReSh_check[n] = np.count_nonzero(TEMP_ReSh == n)

# Print the number of occurrences:
print(TEMP_check)
print(TEMP_ReSh_check)
```

Comment: In NumPy "reshaping" means "changing dimensionality while preserving _all the data_". What you're trying to do gets rid of the first dimension entirely, which is different. Also, `if m == 4 or 6 or 9 or 11` doesn't do what you think it does. _At all_. Please learn some basic Python before trying to use NumPy or reshaping stuff, etc.

Comment: @ForceBru you are being a bit harsh. @kirekik instead of `m == 4 or 6` which is always True because `bool(6)` returns `True`, you should use `m in (4, 6)`. But in your attempt, `m` is undefined so please modify your question.

Comment: @nicoco, well, I went through a situation where I knew _nothing_ about Python and yet was trying to use NumPy and write servers with `socket` and stuff like this. It was a _nightmare_. Nothing was working (obviously), my knowledge of Python was a complete mess, my code was utter trash (this doesn't mean that nowadays my code is much better, though). I believe the OP doesn't want to find themselves in a similar situation, so it'd probably be better to learn the basics first as that'd make everything else much easier to understand.

Comment: @nicoco Thank you for your tip! In have updated the code in the manner by which I interpreted your answer. The number of occurrences of each data value is still not exactly the same, but much more alike, so I could be on the right way.

Comment: There is also something wrong with your fake data. In `randint`, `size` is the shape of the array you create, and the first parameter is the maximum value of your array. So right now, the `TEMP` array does not look like what you describe above, _i.e._, does not have a shape of (n, 4). In fact, I think you're mistaking the number of dimensions of an array and its shape. My guess is that you want to reshape a 2D array of (n, 4) into an array of (n, 3).

Comment: Agreed^^: I believe your test data doesn't contain any info about latitude.  You can infer the month and day value by the index location but this inference is not possible for latitude.  Can you post what the original data looks like?